# When animate nodes names are translated, the Chinese will not display properly

Tags: node-editor, animation-nodes

[image]

Obviously he only supports English, but what can I do to make it show Chinese
(I tried Unicode)

Comment: Does this happen to Animation Nodes only? Does it happen to other parts of blender?

Answer (score -1):

```
def setup(self):
    self.label = "B网格网格BMesh Mesh"
```

great！